# How can I make one line of text bold in a paragraprah JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make `Let's get you registered` bold. With my code it's making all of the text bold, which I don't want.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.page-register-new .variant-body').text('Let`s get you registered. Please fill in the form below and we will email you confirmation that your registration has been completed. All fields are mandatory. ');

  $('this:contains("Let`s get you registered")').css({
    'font-weight': 'bold'
  });
})
```

Comment: As the title says "_one line_", the task is not trivial. The solution depends on the layout, and maintaining a bolded line needs frequent updating if the layout is changed. Perhaps you meant a sentence only ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the text with a `<b>` tag like:

```
$('.variant-body:contains("Let`s get you registered")').html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace(/(Let`s get you registered)/g, '<b>$1</b>');
});
```

DEMO HERE:

```js
$('.page-register-new .variant-body').html('Let`s get you registered. Please fill in the form below and we will email you confirmation that your registration has been completed. All fields are mandatory.');

$('.page-register-new .variant-body:contains("Let`s get you registered")').html(function(_, html) {
  return html.replace(/(Let`s get you registered)/g, '<b>$1</b>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-register-new">
  <div class="variant-body"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot affect the styling of individual words (or groups of words) within a single text node. You need to place that content within its own element and apply styling to that:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.page-register-new .variant-body').html('<span>Let\'s get you registered.</span> Please fill in the form below and we will email you confirmation that your registration has been completed. All fields are mandatory.');
})
```

```css
.page-register-new .variant-body span { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-register-new">
  <div class="variant-body"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you could just use the `b` element directly:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.page-register-new .variant-body').html('<b>Let\'s get you registered.</b> Please fill in the form below and we will email you confirmation that your registration has been completed. All fields are mandatory.');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-register-new">
  <div class="variant-body"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's probably nitpick but `strong` means that the sentence is important / has an important meaning, not that it should be bold (even if most of browser present it as bold). The `<b>` tag might be more appropriate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b

Comment: @Zyigh very good point, thanks. I keep forgetting `b` isn't deprecated any more